# Connect to a Azure SQL Database/SQL Server from Office 365

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, office365

I have a Microsoft Action Pack subscription with Office 365.

I would like to connect to an SQL SERVER database which is provided with Office 365.

I am banging my head on forums and google to find out how to access SQL server in Office 365.

I checked each option but none of them have an SQL SERVER installed.

Does `Office 365` doesn't have `SQL SERVER license`? Do I need something like `Windows Azure which comes with SQL`. I am just lost here.

When I login the office 365 online screen looks like below.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, Office 365 doesn't provide any SQL server service.

Comment: @Serginho I know SharePoint users SQL SERVER and Sharepoint is part of Office 365, so why i can't access SQL server which SharePoint uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, neither SQL Server nor Azure SQL Database come included with an O365 subscription. There are a few options though:

- [Azure SQL Database:](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) To get a $200 free credits to evaluate Azure SQL Database, click "Get Started". Once you have your Azure account, you can [create your first Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/) and then [connect and query from Excel](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connect-excel/), for example.
- [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx): A free version of SQL Server than you can install on your laptop, server, or in an Azure VM.
- MSDN: If you have an MSDN subscription, SQL Server Developer edition is included for free.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this page, https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/action-pack-software-licensing-benefits-faq.aspx, it does look like Microsoft Action Pack includes some product keys for software and Azure Credits. The Azure credits could be used towards Azure SQL DB if a product key for SQL Server is not part of the action pack bundle (I don't see it listed, but it isn't entirely clear to me what products are included).