# Office JS API fails to write less than 10000 cell values to a table

Tags: office-js

We are working with office js API to write data to a table. The code was working fine until the end of November 2016 on excel online and it stopped working after that.

The code just set the values to a table and the total number of cells it is trying to write is less than 10,000 and the method to set the value is:

```
dataTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [data.headerValues];
dataTable.getDataBodyRange().formulas = data.values;
dataTable.getTotalRowRange().formulas = [data.totalRow];
```

The complete code to reproduce the issue is hosted in [GitHub](https://github.com/renil-abdulkader/office-js-api-testing)

You can run the code in office online using the manifest below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>5B1D06A5-5F14-4B8F-B07D-E698084397F6</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Provider</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Testing Office API" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Testing Office API"/>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://renil-abdulkader.github.io/office-js-api-testing/" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Clicking on the Load Data button will only write part of the data and console will show below error: `{"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"GeneralException","message":"There was an internal error while processing the request.","traceMessages":[],"debugInfo":{"errorLocation":"Range.formulas"}}`.

Other issues once this happened are:

1. Adding the binding will fail
2. Once the binding is failed, delete tab will start to fail
3. If there are multiple users on the excel sheet, users will start getting `You are no longer connected to the server` error message.

Update 1: There are 68 rows we are writing and 136 columns per row. Updated the code to write first 40 rows and last 30 rows and that code is working fine, but not the entire 68 rows. So there shouldn't be an issue with the data itself.

Comment: I suspect that you have reached the limits of storage for Excel. For a user of the size of the one suggested by the manifest, you would need to use a database to store the data. [Connect to a Azure SQL Database/SQL Server from Office 365](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35387508/1115360) may lead you to a solution.

Comment: Where is the storage limit specified?

Comment: This data won't definitely reach the 10MB limit and as I mentioned, this was working fine earlier.

Comment: Sure. Updated the error information I got from office API. Also, you can run the code with the manifest provided above if you would like.

Comment: Well, that's not a very helpful error message. I would suspect corrupt/bad data and to track it down I'd use a for-loop to add the formulas one at a time.

Comment: Agreed, but that's how office API report errors. If you look at the data, there is actually no values coming in and shouldn't cause issues. I have tried writing the first 50 rows and last 30 rows separately and both worked without errors. So it must not be related to data it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to actually try it out. Hopefully someone else will come along and be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Unable to re-produce the error. I tested on Office 365 tenant. This data in itself won't affect the 10MB size limit. So, that's not the issue. Looks like this is on O365 Excel Online (not on-premise OOS). Could you try with a new file and check if the error is occurs then? Perhaps test with under different user?

Comment: Able to reproduce the error. Will get back with a response.

Answer (score 0):

This is  due to time-out error on the online platform. As a mitigation step, is it possible to do large formula (or values) update in chunks so that there is no one single request that runs into time out issue? What that chunk size is may depend on the environment. Perhaps 2K cells to begin with? 
I'll follow-up on this thread if we are able to provide an alternate solution.

Comment: So not using table.formulas setter and instead using range to set values instead? We can definitely try. But when we tried batch promises, it didn't work. I can update the code to do batch and see if I can reproduce the error.

Comment: Both value or formula set will trigger re-calculation. So, I don't think it makes a difference. If you are setting formula, you should use formula property. By "'chunk' I meant to say, update (values or formulas) by breaking up your original grid into smaller grids. Instead of say 10k cell update, doing 5 updates of 2k cells. I'll get back on whether timeout limit can be extended. 
Regardless, for online (browser) clients, you want to account for user experience as well. Ideally, you don't want the "working on it.." message for too long. Otherwise, user may cancel or close.

Comment: I think writing in chunks will make the "Working on it..." message to stay longer. I will update the code and will let you know.

Comment: How do we do loop with multiple ctx.sync() as in this case where we need to write batch data? Any documentation I can follow?